# How to replace font family in specific web pages - Firefox 55.x.xx

Tags: firefox, fonts

On Windows 10, ClearType is off, some fonts in web pages looks ugly, for example in PayPal site `"PayPal-Sans"`:
[image]
But `"Arial"` or `"Tahoma"` looks excellent. Is it possible to replace specific fonts to `"Arial"` or other types by using CSS or some script in Firefox 55.x.xx? I've tried some solutions, but it seems in Firefox 55 version it is no longer working..

[This](http://www.keyvan.net/2010/10/helvetica-on-firefox/) method does not work:
at `./Profiles/some_profile.default/chrome/userContent.css` file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'PayPal-Sans';
src: local('Arial');
}
```

My goal is to make it look like this - `"Arial"` font:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally - found temporary solution :)

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain(www.paypal.com) { 

  * {
    font-family: "Arial" !important;
  }

  .moreIcon,
  .vx_icon vx_icon-small,
  .vx_icon-arrow-right-half-small,
  .mer-notifications-nav-icon,
  .mer-settings-nav-icon {
    font-family: "paypal-vx-icons" !important;
  }

  span.caret,
  a.secondaryButton,
  .icon, .caret {
    font-family: "consumer-icons" !important;
  }
}
```

Now PayPal looks ok again :)